# Problem - dark Border around Render Frame with Eevee Reflection Plane

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, reflection, lightprobe

I'm just testing Eevee and got a strange border in the reflection on the ground.
The ground has  an easy shader wich is very glossy.
In the viewport all is corect but if I render it, I got this strange result.
I've play around with the settings of the material, render settings and the object data of the Reflection Plane (Light Probe).

I hope anyone can solve this problem.

Thank you[image]

[image]

Comment: Now I see that the problem i still in the render-viewport too. In this case the dark border is outside of the camera frame. It's above the timeline. The Edge Fading of Screen Space Reflections is on value 0.000

Answer (score 1):

Solution!
*Render Settings > Film*  set *Overscan* to Active

It seems that Blender trimms the area outside the camera frame and dosen't consider this informations. That's the origin of the problem. A falloff starts form there. The overscan option let some information outsite the camera frame and the effect dosen't occure.

Why this musst be like that - I don't know.